# Compare dynamic text in while loop in cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress

how to grab dynamic text inside then method which is inside while loop and compare it while condition in cypress.since the scope of the text variable within then method, i'm unable to get updated text and compare in while condition.

Answer (score 0):

You can take the reference of below link where I have answered regarding returning the text of a locator to subsequent chainer. You have to tweak it according to your problem. Basically since you are returning text so you can easily compare it. As  you didn't show your code snippet and the problem, so I thought off sharing this link with you
[Storing an element's text in Cypress outside of a chainer method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61766924/storing-an-elements-text-in-cypress-outside-of-a-chainer-method/61767217#61767217)

Comment: Hi Srinu,thank you for your reply, I modified my code. now the while loop is not iterating. please correct me where im wrong

Comment: .cy.get('.dx-data-row > td:nth-child(2)').then(ele => { //Grabbing text         
        return ele.text()
      }).then(eleValue => {
    while(eleValue!=='Credit User' && counter < 20){ //Comparing grabbed text
        cy.get('.search').click()    
    cy.wait(3000) 
    return cy.get('.dx-data-row > td:nth-child(2)').then(ele => { //Grabbing updated text after search button clicked and again need to compare
        return ele.text()
      }).then(eleValue => {
        cy.log('text is ' + eleValue);
        
      });
      counter ++      
    }
})

Comment: In start, you have to put `return` before `cy.get('.dx-data-row >)`. Also please try to put `cy.log()` and debug in every statement accordingly and see what are missing things

Comment: Thank you, let me try will get back to you.

Comment: Hi Srinu, sorry for late reply, since im new to cypress and programming took me for ever to find out where the problem is. So after removed return keyword from then method inside while loop, its started iterating.But now the problem is, it keep continue iterating til 20 iterations completed.Because its not comparing with updated string in while loop. pls assist.

Comment: return cy.get('.dx-data-row > td:nth-child(2)').then(ele => { //Grabbing text 
return ele.text() }).then(eleValue => { 
while(eleValue!=='Credit User' && counter < 20){ //Comparing grabbed text 
cy.get('.search').click()
 cy.wait(3000)
 cy.get('.dx-data-row > td:nth-child(2)').then(ele => { //Grabbing updated text after search button clicked and again need to compare 
return ele.text() }).then(eleValue => { 
cy.log('text is ' + eleValue);
 }); 
counter ++
 }
 });