# How to extract text content from a div using Cypress?

Tags: javascript, cypress, end-to-end

I want to get a text from a div with a class name of `.inventory_item_name`. The HTML looks like this:

```html
<div class="inventory_item_name">Backpack</div>
```

And my JS code is as follow:

```js
const article = cy.get('.inventory_item_price').then((theElement) => {
  theElement.text();
});
```

The problem: When I do `cy.log(article)` I get `Object{5}`

Comment: you cannot assign or work with the return values of any cypress command. Commands are enqueued and run asynchronously. The first hint will be `cy.get('div').should('have.text', 'Backpack')` in case you try to assert on element’s text content

Answer (score 9):

Just like Alex mentioned in the comment, you cannot return a value from `cy` commands. But you can do so in the `.then` block just like:

```js
it("should have text of 'Backpack'", () => {
  // I have changed the selector since the class name in your HTML is ".inventory_item_name" not ".inventory_item_price"
  cy.get('.inventory_item_name').then(($el) => {
    const text = $el.text(); // Now you have the text "Backpack"

    // Do the assertion here
    expect(text).to.eq('Backpack');
  });
});
```

You can learn more about why Cypress doesn't return value in this [documentation](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/introduction-to-cypress.html#Cypress-is-Like-jQuery)

Answer (score 2):

You can't assign text values like this.

```
const article = cy.get('.inventory_item_price').then((theElement) => {
      theElement.text();
   });
```

The reason is the bellow code does not return a text element.

```
cy.get('.inventory_item_price').then((theElement) => {
          theElement.text();
       });
```

So you need to change it like this.

```
cy.get('.inventory_item_price').then((theElement) => {
         const article = theElement.text();
         //not you can use article
       });
```

Answer (score 0):

As cypress documentation says

> You cannot assign or work with the return values of any
> Cypress command. Commands are enqueued and run asynchronously.

```
// this won't work the way you think it does
const button = cy.get('button')
const form = cy.get('form')
button.click()
```

For more information refer : [variables-and-aliases](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/variables-and-aliases.html#Return-Values)

You have a few options. But you need to keep in mind the asynchronous nature of cypress

- Use alias (if you want to share the article variable in other tests ) so the code will look like this,

Example:

```
it("Test 1", () => {
cy.get('.inventory_item_price').invoke('text').as('article')
})

//Now you can use this.article in all the other test cases
//If you are using aliases remember Not to use arrow functions on hooks

it("Test 2", function(){
//this will log Backpack
cy.log(this.article)
})
```

- Use `.then`, As mentioned by @konekoya in the answer, Since cypress is asynchronous you need to use `.then` to execute a task after a previous task is completed.

Example:

```
cy.get('.inventory_item_price').invoke('text').then(article=> {
//you can use articale variable as much as you want inside .then 
//you can't use it outside

const value = articale ;
cy.log(article)
cy.log(value )
})
```

Note: to get inner Text you there are several methods. You can do the same thing using,

```
cy.get('.inventory_item_price').then(article => {
const value = articale.text() ;
cy.log(article.text())
cy.log(value)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I was working on a cypress project and came across this question. So, I decided to simulate it. I therefore included the line
`<div class="inventory_item_name">Backpack</div>`in the project as below:

```
<div class="form-group row">
  <label class="col-sm-3 label">Radios</label>
  <div class="col-sm-9">
    <nb-radio-group>
      <nb-radio>Option 1</nb-radio>
      <nb-radio>Option 2</nb-radio>
      <nb-radio disabled>Disabled Option</nb-radio>
    </nb-radio-group>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group row">
  <div class="offset-sm-3 col-sm-9">
    <button type="submit" nbButton status="primary">Sign in</button>
    <br><br>
    <div class="inventory_item_name">Backpack</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This updated my DOM as below:

[image]

Now, when we write the code below to see the output of the `text` variable, we see in the image that follows that it is `Backpack` circled in red. Why is that?

It is `Backpack` because `Backpack` is the descendent DOM element of `.inventory_item_name`

```
cy.get('.inventory_item_name').then((el) => {
    const text = el.text();
    console.log(text);
    expect(text).to.eq('Backpack');
});
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can return the article text with below code. Please also look at the link where I have shared the answer for more details.

[Storing an element's text in Cypress outside of a chainer method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61766924/storing-an-elements-text-in-cypress-outside-of-a-chainer-method/61767217#61767217)

```
return cy.get('.inventory_item_price').then((theElement) => {
      return theElement.text();
    }).then(article => {
      cy.log(`article is ${article}`);
    })
```

Comment: I want to store the price in an variable called price and then I want to make a test with this variable. I tried to overwrite your code but this doesn't help. Maybe you can show me how to do.